# Travelling merchant disappearing

Tags: terraria

I was playing terraria, and "Travelling Merchant has arrived!" appeared. I was happy, so, having no recall potions/magic mirror (early-game) quit the world, then rejoined at my spawnpoint. The travelling merchant was gone. This happened to me before, but I used a magic mirror, and he was gone too. I searched half the map; he wasn't there. Help me I want his wares!!!

Answer (score 1):

The traveling merchant should appear at your house. He spawns at a random time between 4:30pm and 12:00pm and leaves at 6:00pm. When he spawns you get the message "A traveling merchant has arrived" and when he leaves you get the message "The traveling merchant has departed"

If you can't find your traveling merchant you could check a few places.

-Your world spawn (Where your character first spawned and where all other characters will spawn)

-Your house (He could be Outside, Inside, Above, or Below depending if there is room.)

-Any pits or holes near by your house. (He might have fallen and possibly died.)

You could also look for his icon on the world map. He should be near by your base so start there.

Comment: -world spawn: built my house there, house: not there, pits: none, map: forgot XD